Reorg happens regularly on async backing parachain
When testing different async backing parachains (parachain-template-node/moonriver-local/ajuna-local) with different polkadot versions (rococo-local), these parachains can generate blocks every 6 seconds. However, the reorg situation happens regularly after several blocks. Does somebody encounter this?
For example: parachain-template-node
2024-07-17 15:13:18 [Relaychain] ♻️   Reorg on #22,0x9bd6…275f to #22,0x82ec…f7a6, common ancestor #21,0x7f18…5566    
2024-07-17 15:13:18 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #11,0x774a…c87c to #12,0xc4a7…654c, common ancestor #9,0x6e95…d239    
2024-07-17 15:13:24 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #12,0xc4a7…654c to #13,0x7da0…5168, common ancestor #11,0xd7ac…8e59    
2024-07-17 15:14:06 [Relaychain] ♻️   Reorg on #30,0x645f…89e1 to #30,0xb919…fb18, common ancestor #29,0xe669…d5d5    
2024-07-17 15:14:18 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #20,0x6507…cfdc to #21,0xb5eb…c3a1, common ancestor #18,0x0299…95fe    
2024-07-17 15:14:54 [Relaychain] ♻️   Reorg on #37,0x9e20…3a90 to #38,0x2385…84f7, common ancestor #36,0x3d1c…3733    
2024-07-17 15:14:54 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #26,0x7a6d…bab5 to #27,0x38bc…f963, common ancestor #25,0x1b33…b52d    
2024-07-17 15:15:18 [Relaychain] ♻️   Reorg on #42,0xdc95…444f to #42,0xb37d…1217, common ancestor #41,0xf38e…4670    
2024-07-17 15:15:18 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #29,0x237f…1f6e to #30,0x369d…fc8e, common ancestor #27,0x38bc…f963    
2024-07-17 15:15:24 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #30,0x369d…fc8e to #31,0x260e…8a3a, common ancestor #29,0xbac3…2529    
2024-07-17 15:16:18 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #38,0x1a45…4ab3 to #39,0x4866…b26a, common ancestor #36,0xa453…6073    
2024-07-17 15:17:18 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #47,0x309d…58f9 to #48,0x53c1…410d, common ancestor #45,0x3412…2da2    
2024-07-17 15:18:18 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #56,0x0a5e…4146 to #57,0x48c3…b27c, common ancestor #54,0x024c…1909    
2024-07-17 15:19:18 [Relaychain] ♻️   Reorg on #81,0x380c…82a5 to #82,0x1156…6aab, common ancestor #80,0x5b28…a561    
2024-07-17 15:19:18 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #65,0x06b5…4f8a to #66,0x709a…3f11, common ancestor #63,0xc68c…7291    
2024-07-17 15:19:42 [Relaychain] ♻️   Reorg on #86,0x0002…8ce3 to #86,0xf0d2…b518, common ancestor #85,0x628c…0245    
2024-07-17 15:19:48 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #70,0x6aa6…7ca7 to #71,0x3202…0851, common ancestor #69,0xce73…9bc8    
2024-07-17 15:20:06 [Relaychain] ♻️   Reorg on #90,0x2ee5…470f to #90,0x242c…85a5, common ancestor #89,0xe4ba…0a89    
2024-07-17 15:20:18 [Parachain] ♻️   Reorg on #74,0xca48…2702 to #75,0x44da…7a2e, common ancestor #72,0xcf47…2f9e    



You are using rococo-local for the relay chain. This has a session length of 1 minute. Parachain consensus on the relay chain is not supporting backing/approving parachain blocks across this "border". So, these blocks are thrown away. This leads to the behavior that you are seeing.
So, you could for example increase the session length by changing this line to 10 * minutes. Be aware that this increases the time to onboard your parachain.
On the production networks the session length is 4 hours for Polkadot and 1 hour for Kusama.

Thanks for your reply. On the relay chain, there is my rococo-local's chain spec. I believe it will follow the default settings. Generally, the reorgs should be fine, but that happens too frequently. It's a little strange. Or maybe it's related to my laptop's hardware specs?

Not related to your hardware. See my answer to your github issue here: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/5076
